# Handle mutliple different data types in same function

Tags: haskell

In haskell, is it possible to create a function capable of handling multiple different datatypes for input and output?

For example, lets assume a function capable of doing pattern matching on [Char] and Int returning both datatypes respectively.

```hs
fun 1 = 2
fun "textIn" = "textOut"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can define a typeclass. This is however similar to *overloading* in other languages: you define functions with the same name, but with a different type signatures.

Comment: The short answer: yes, it is. For example, the `id` function does that. The long answer: your question too abstract. You have a lot of options to do that in haskell (type classes, ADT/GADT, class Typeable, etc).

Comment: **Why** do you want to do that? Sounds like an [X-Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Willem Van Onsem points out, you can do something with a typeclass:

```hs
class Fun a where
  fun :: a -> a

instance Fun Integer where
  fun 1 = 2

instance Fun String where
  fun "textIn" = "textOut"
```

Whether this is *sensible* depends on the situation. Designing good classes is difficult, and I strongly recommend that Haskell beginners steer entirely clear of it. Start by learning to design your own functions and types, and to declare instances of standard/library classes.

---

freestyle points out that you can do something with algebraic data types (ADTs), and I think that's a *much better* place to start.

```hs
data Funny
  = FunnyInteger Integer
  | FunnyString String
  deriving Show -- so you can print these in GHCi

fun :: Funny -> Funny
fun (FunnyInteger 1) = FunnyInteger 2
fun (FunnyString "textIn") = FunnyString "textOut"
```

---

freestyle also mentions generalized algebraic data types (GADTs). These are *definitely* not for beginners, but as a hint toward the future...

```hs
data FooTy a where
  FooInteger :: FooTy Integer
  FooString :: FooTy String

foo :: FooTy a -> a -> a
foo FooInteger 1 = 2
foo FooString "textIn" = "textOut"
```

Comment: A fourth option is to use Typeable.

Comment: Instead of the `Funny` type you could use `Either`.   This might be appropriate for a very localized bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

By class `Typeable`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Control.Monad
import Data.Typeable
import Data.Foldable

fun :: Typeable a => a -> Maybe a
fun x = asum $ map ($x)
    [ appT $ \(x::Int) -> 2 <$ guard (x == 1)
    , appT $ \(x::String) -> "textOut" <$ guard (x == "textIn")
    ]

appT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (b -> Maybe b) -> a -> Maybe a
appT f x = cast =<< f =<< cast x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ fun (1 :: Int)
    print $ fun "textIn"
    print $ fun [1 :: Int, 2]
```

Output:

```
Just 2
Just "textOut"
Nothing
```

`appT` is helper function (maybe it's in some package).
You can also see: [`Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html), [`syb`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb).

But this is not Haskell idiomatic way usually.